# Iterating over xml response on python

Tags: python, xml

I have this structure on a xml response

```
<reponse xmls="http://www.some.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.some.com/ot ot.xsd ">
<OneTree> </OneTree> 
<TwoTree> 
    <count>10</count>
    <alist>
        <aelement>
            <Name>FirstEntry</Name>
        </aelement>
        <aelement>
            <Name>FirstEntry</Name>
        </aelement>
    </alist>

</TwoTree>
```

And I'm trying to print out the value on Names

So far I've managed to print the value of `<count>`

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

for child in tree:
if (child.tag == '{http://www.some.com/ot}TwoTree'):
    print child[0].text
```

I'm having problem getting the tree on `<alist>` and the printing out Names, looking for tags or attrib are not working for this structure. Little help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier using `findall()` method which accepts [basic XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax) :

```
namespaces = {'d': 'http://www.some.com'}
result = tree.findall('.//d:Name', namespaces)
print [r.text for r in result]
```

**[complete demo](https://eval.in/533054) :**

```
raw = '''<response xmlns="http://www.some.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.some.com/ot ot.xsd ">
<OneTree> </OneTree> 
<TwoTree> 
    <count>10</count>
    <alist>
        <aelement>
            <Name>FirstEntry</Name>
        </aelement>
        <aelement>
            <Name>FirstEntry</Name>
        </aelement>
    </alist>

</TwoTree> 
</response>'''

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(raw)
namespaces = {'d': 'http://www.some.com'}
result = tree.findall('.//d:Name', namespaces)
print [r.text for r in result]
```

**output :**

```
['FirstEntry', 'FirstEntry']
```